# How to transfer focus from datagrid to button?

Tags: c#, button, datagrid, user-controls

```
protected override void Paint(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, CurrencyManager source, int rowNum, Brush backBrush, Brush foreBrush, bool alignToRight)
{
    RectangleF textBounds;// Bounds of text 
    Object cellData;// Object to show in the cell 

    DrawBackground(g, bounds, rowNum, backBrush);// Draw cell background

    bounds.Inflate(-2, -2);// Shrink cell by couple pixels for text.

    textBounds = new RectangleF(bounds.X, bounds.Y, bounds.Width, bounds.Height);
    // Set text bounds.
    cellData = this.PropertyDescriptor.GetValue(source.List[rowNum]);   // Get data for this cell from data source.

    g.DrawString(FormatText(cellData), this.Owner.Font, foreBrush, textBounds, this.StringFormat);
    // Render contents 
    this.updateHostedControl();// Update floating hosted control.
}

// Would reposition, hide and show hosted control as needed.
protected void updateHostedControl()
{
    Rectangle selectedBounds = this.Owner.GetCellBounds(this.Owner.CurrentCell.RowNumber, this.Owner.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber);
    // Get selected cell bounds.
    // We only need to show hosted control if column is not read only, 
    // selected cell is in our column and not occluded by anything.

    if (!this.ReadOnly && (this.ColumnOrdinal == this.Owner.CurrentCell.ColumnNumber) &&
         this.Owner.HitTest(selectedBounds.Left, selectedBounds.Top).Type == DataGrid.HitTestType.Cell &&
         this.Owner.HitTest(selectedBounds.Right, selectedBounds.Bottom).Type == DataGrid.HitTestType.Cell)
    {
        if (selectedBounds != this._bounds)// See if control bounds are already set.
        {
            this._bounds = selectedBounds; // Store last bounds. Note we can't use control's bounds 
            // as some controls are not resizable and would change bounds as they pleased.
            this.HostedControl.Bounds = selectedBounds;// Update control bounds.

            this.HostedControl.Focus();
            this.HostedControl.Update();// And update control now so it looks better visually.
        }

        if (!this.HostedControl.Visible)// If control is not yet visible...
        {
            this.HostedControl.Show();// Show it
            this.HostedControl.Focus();
        }
    }
    else if (this.HostedControl.Visible)// Hosted control should not be visible. Check if it is.
    {
        this.HostedControl.Hide();// Hide it.
    }

}

protected virtual void DrawBackground(Graphics g, Rectangle bounds, int rowNum, Brush backBrush)
{
    Brush background = backBrush;// Use default brush by... hmm... default.

    if ((null != background) && ((rowNum & 1) != 0) && !Owner.IsSelected(rowNum))
    {                                                                   
        // If have alternating brush, row is odd and not selected...
        background = _alternatingBrush;// Then use alternating brush.
    }
    else
        background = new SolidBrush(Color.White);

    g.FillRectangle(background, bounds);// Draw cell background
}
```

I Have incuded one custom datagrid and button, I am unable write code to transfer focus from datagrid to button.By default datagrid or button will have focus. Please can anybody help me on this.I want focus to be transfered when ENter key pressed.

Advance Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use KeyPressed event on datagrid, check is Enter key is pressed and then focus button. This should work, if you dont have any specific problems:

```
private void datagrid_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
      button1.Focus();
}
```

Comment: If I press Enter Key the particular row value is editing but not transfering focus to button

Comment: 1. you want that user could edit value or your datagrid must be readonly? 2. show how you filling datagrid. 3. think about accepting answers to your older questions.

Comment: datagrid is editable(it is customised datagrid) in which I have added 1 textbox and 1 combobox

Comment: I am new to this site well I don't know how to add code. I am giving brief explanation I have created 3 classes 1: DataGridCustomColumnBase-which sets the properties of column  2:DataGridCustomTextbox:which adds textbox control to the datagrid 3:DataGridCustomCombobox:which adds combobox control to the datagrid

Comment: @Shilpa, Edit your question with any new information. There is an "edit" link just beneath your question for that very purpose.

Comment: Just copy your code, press edit link in your question, paste code in question, select pasted code and press {} button to format your code automatically.